# Identity in Informix

Tags: sql, informix, ddl

I'm using Informix and I want to create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE increment_table 
 (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    increment_column INTEGER IDENTITY (START WITH 2000, INCREMENT BY 1), 
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```

But when I run the statement, the result is a syntax error after the INTEGER keyword. I suppose is because Informix does not support this keyword IDENTITY.

Can you help me in some ideas of how can I create an auto increment column, with this characteristics:

1. The column need to increment automatically in every insert.
2. The column isn't primary key.
3. Allows me set the initial number of start and the value of increment.
4. Can edit the value of the column.
5. The table already have a serial column.

Comment: `IDENTITY (START WITH 2000, INCREMENT BY 1)` is not part of the SQL standard - where did you find that syntax? And why do you think that should work with Informix?

Comment: As far as I can tell [from the Informix manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0111.htm#ids_sqs_0111) there is no option for auto incrementing columns at all

Comment: SERIAL , BIGSERIAL, SERIAL8 data type are the only auto increment at Informix and it's allowed only one by table. You already have SERIAL at "id" column. If you need other column with auto-increment you should use SEQUENCES for that, but will be a manually treatment at your SQLs or you maybe try embedded it using triggers .

Comment: Presumably you'll have a unique constraint on the 'increment column' since you want it to be an identifying column.  You can have one SERIAL and also either one BIGSERIAL or one SERIAL8 column (use BIGSERIAL if you go this route).  You can set the start value for any of the serial types; you can only use an increment of 1.  Otherwise, you could use a SEQUENCE, maybe tied to the table with triggers.  You can have increments other than 1 with sequences.  Since serial columns cannot be updated, you probably need to use a sequence instead.